# Data-logging from an i2c-connected Atlas Scientific Sensor to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi3, i2c, atlas

I am relatively new to Python, and programming as a whole. I am progressively getting the hang of it, however I have been stumped as of late in regards to one of my latest projects. I have a set of Atlas Scientific EZO circuits w/ their corresponding sensors hooked up to my Raspberry Pi 3. I can run the i2c script fine, and the majority of the code makes sense to me. However, I would like to pull data from the sensors and log it with a time stamp in a CSV file, taking data points in timed intervals. I am not quite sure how to pull the data from the sensor, and put it into a CSV. Making CSVs in Python is fairly simple, as is filling them with data, but I cannot seem to understand how I would make the data that goes into the CSV the same as what is displayed in the terminal when one runs the Poll function. Attached is the i2c sample code from Atlas' website. I have annotated it a bit more so as to help me understand it better.

I have already attempted to make sense of the poll function, but am confused in regards to the self.file_write and self.file_read methods used throughout the code. I do believe they would be of use in this instance but I am generally stumped in terms of implementation. Below you will find a link to the Python script (i2c.py) written by Atlas Scientific

https://github.com/AtlasScientific/Raspberry-Pi-sample-code/blob/master/i2c.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing by "the polling function" you are referring to this section of the code:

```
# continuous polling command automatically polls the board
        elif user_cmd.upper().startswith("POLL"):
            delaytime = float(string.split(user_cmd, ',')[1])

            # check for polling time being too short, change it to the minimum timeout if too short
            if delaytime < AtlasI2C.long_timeout:
                print("Polling time is shorter than timeout, setting polling time to %0.2f" % AtlasI2C.long_timeout)
                delaytime = AtlasI2C.long_timeout

            # get the information of the board you're polling
            info = string.split(device.query("I"), ",")[1]
            print("Polling %s sensor every %0.2f seconds, press ctrl-c to stop polling" % (info, delaytime))

            try:
                while True:
                    print(device.query("R"))
                    time.sleep(delaytime - AtlasI2C.long_timeout)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:       # catches the ctrl-c command, which breaks the loop above
                print("Continuous polling stopped")
```

If this is the case  then if looks like you can recycle most of this code for your use. You can grab the string you are seeing in your console with device.query("R"), instead of printing it, grab the return value and write it to your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should add method to AtlasI2C class which will write data to file

Just type under AtlasI2C **init**() this method:

```
def update_file(self, new_data):
    with open(self.csv_file, 'a') as data_file:
        try:
            data = "{}\n".format(str(new_data))
            data_file.write(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

add to AtlasI2C init statement about csv file name:

```
self.csv_file = <my_filename>.csv # replace my_filename with ur name
```

and then under line 51 (char_list = list(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x) & ~0x80), list(response[1:]))) add this line:

```
self.update_file(''.join(char_list))
```

Hope its gonna help You.

Cheers, 
Fenrir